# The json returned by struts2's json plug-in contains special characters being escaped

Tags: struts2

{"pics": "http: //// localhost: 8080 // data // photos // moodsPic // 4.jpg"}

I want "jpg / 4.jpg" effect

Another way:

After escaping, return to http: ////// localhost: 8080 /// data /// photos /// moodsPic /// 4.jpg

The result becomes like this: http: //////// localhost: 8080 //// data //// photos //// moodsPic //// 4.jpg

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. There aren't any special characters in that string.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot duplicate this and I do not see escaped forward slashes.
Please make sure your struts package extends json-default like below example:

```
<package name="urlMappingsExample" extends="json-default">
```